# Sql query to find last item in a date

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have got 2 tables in a sqlite database: Chats and Inboxcache. I need to join both the tables , and create a list of inbox items.

Inbox items will have all the records from inbox cache and find the latest chat item for that inbox(conversation) and get its text.

Here is the sql statement I have currently.

```
SELECT ch.ConversationID, Max(ch.Time) As Date, ch.Text, ic.SenderMessageName, ic.IsReader FROM ConversationHistoryDocument ch INNER JOIN InboxCache ic ON ic.ConversationID = ch.ConversationID WHERE ch.ConversationID ='{conversationId}' GROUP BY ch.ConversationID ORDER BY ch.Time Desc
```

It works great in most cases, but if the chat table has got the records with same datetime. When it does the inner join on inbox cache table it picks the first record. But I need the last one. How should I change the SQL statement for this?

Comment: if the time only shows date (YYYY/MM/DD) I would suggest you add clock too. if u have add clock as well, I would suggest to make clock more precise, micro seconds or mili seconds

Comment: Could you share sample data and expected result please.

Comment: @AFarmanbar : Time is saved in epoch  time (unix ticks)

Comment: @LibinJoseph so i would suggest to use record's index, higher index has priority, in WHERE clause.

Comment: @LibinJoseph you can use this as well `Max(index)` in SELECT statement .

Comment: If there are 2 rows for a ConversationID with the same max(Time) how is the last one defined?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
with cte as (select *,row_number()over(order by time desc)rn from seConversationHistoryDocument )

SELECT ch.ConversationID, Max(ch.Time) As Date, ch.Text, ic.SenderMessageName, ic.IsReader 
FROM cte ch INNER JOIN InboxCache ic ON ic.ConversationID = ch.ConversationID 
WHERE ch.ConversationID ='{conversationId}' GROUP BY ch.ConversationID ORDER BY ch.Time Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ch.ConversationID,  
  min(ch.Time) AS DATE,  
  ch.Text,
  ic.SenderMessageName,
  ic.IsReader
FROM ConversationHistoryDocument ch
INNER JOIN InboxCache ic
ON ic.ConversationID    = ch.ConversationID
WHERE ch.ConversationID ='{conversationId}'
GROUP BY ch.ConversationID
ORDER BY ch.Time DESC
```